# Keyboard shortcut to move columns in WORD table

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts

To move lines in a WORD table up and down I use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd>.

Is there a similar way to move columns in a table to the left or to the right?

I've searched many advice sites but couldn't find a reference to this (*the advice is usually to drag and drop or to cut and paste etc*).
It doesn't appear in the relevant [Microsoft site](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-for-Microsoft-Word-9a2e0234-e682-49ff-a4aa-999f07b51bf3?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1), but since the keys to move lines up and down aren't mentioned directly either (*the combination* <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd> *is only mentioned for moving paragraphs in text*) -

I'm still keeping a little flame of hope that such a thing does exist...
Anyone?

Comment: as you mentioned your existing shortcuts are originally move paragraph, and eventually does the same for rows too. As moving to right / left isn't applicable for paragraphs, probably there is no such shortcut exists. Also I've tried recording a macro during pressing your shortcuts, and it recorded [`Selection.Range.Relocate wdRelocateDown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192827.aspx), also this has only directions up and down. Your workaround could be to write a macro (cut & paste), however that'll be tricky as word vba can't work with tables containing merged cells.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with standard keyboard shortcuts, cutting and pasting, so not the same as moving column by column like with the rows, but still affective and quick:

1. Select the entire column you want to move
2. Press Ctrl+X, this removes the column from the table and copies it to the Clipboard
3. Move the insertion point to the beginning of the top cell of the column before which you want to place the column you just cut
4. Press Ctrl+V

Alternatively you can do the same via dragging and dropping:

1. Select the entire column that you want to move
2. Click on the highlighted column, and hold down the left mouse button. Shortly the pointer should change to a “ghost” insertion point with a small box next to the pointer arrow
3. Drag the column to the place where you want it to be. You should position the insertion point in the column before which your movedcolumn will appear.
4. Release the mouse button, the column is now moved